# hgignore regex expression for excluding all files except 1 folder

Tags: regex, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to ignore all .SQL files, except if they are under the DatabaseSchema folder.

This is the regex expression I came up with:

```
^(?!DatabaseSchema\\).*\.sql$
```

This seems to work on all the regex testing sites (for example http://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/) but when I run it through mercurial it doesn't ignore either of these test files:

```
DatabaseSchema\test.sql
testRoot.sql
```

I'm using syntax: glob at the start of my hgignore before switching to regex at the end for this 1 case by using "syntax: regex".

Is there something I'm missing about the way mercurial uses regex in the hgignore file?

Comment: `syntax: regex` ? shouldn't that be `syntax: regexp` ?

Comment: OMG that was it.  I went back and looked at some of the earlier examples I was seeing online and the one I started with had "regex" and I never noticed that all the others had regexp.  Thank you a ton!

Comment: I can imagine that you shouted Homer's catchword Doh! after you realised it.

Comment: More than just doh.  It was a string of 4 letter words :)